# draw a Google graph with sql table

Tags: php, sql

I used Google graph to draw a graph with variables in a sql table, below is my code, as you see it draws a graph with the last row of table, how to draw 3 last row? I know that I should use `DESC LIMIT 3` but how?

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM result ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $value=array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $year=$r['year'];
        $sales=$r['sales'];
        $expenses=$r['expenses'];
        $val="[".$year.",".$sales.",".$expenses."]";
        array_push($value,$val );
    }
    $final_value = implode(",", $value);
?>

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        <?php echo $final_value?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for real? You already know the answer!

```
SELECT * FROM result ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Change that to

```
SELECT * FROM result ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

???

Comment: No just keep it the same :)